# Excel Text Join: Extract Cell Values From Duplicated Column Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, textjoin

I have the following scenario:

I have repeated values in Column C and Column D. I have some values in column E.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVfTc.png)

Output required: I have the unique values of column C in the Column K and unique values of column D distributed in Row 4 (L4:R4).

I want to join texts from Column E if the values in Column C and Column D matches. I want the following.

[Output Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdGMW.png)

How to do this in excel using functions (no VBA)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `L5`:

`=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,FILTER($D$5:$D$19,($B$5:$B$19=$K5)*($C$5:$C$19=L$4),""))`

and copied right and down.

You'll need to `Wrap Text` in these cells and set the `Row Height` appropriately in order to see your desired linebreak delimitation.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I do not have the filter function in Excel. I have found a solution.

Comment: filter is for Excel / Office 365 only. Neverland If you found an answer then you may upload it for others